# is (i % 3 == 0) means ( i % 3 == false )?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, modulus

I am a beginner learning JS. Can anyone explain to me why "1" on the output?

here it is:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    i += 2;
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    i++;
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```

output : 1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 16

I can figure out why the output equal to 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 16 , however, I don't understand why 1 is there as output...

Comment: No, it means `i % 3 == 0`, however `false` is loosely equal to `0`.

Comment: `1` is not fully divisible by either `2` or `3`, so it's not changed.

Comment: 1 is there because both if conditions are false on the first loop.

Comment: for the same reason `5 and 11` are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of `i` is `1`, both conditional statement you defined doesn't get executed.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log( 'inside if' );
    i += 2;
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log( 'inside else-if' );
    i++;
  } else {
    console.log( 'neither if nor else-if' );
  }
  
  console.log(i);
}
```

Remainder is always `1` when you divide it with `2` or `3`, which is not equals to `0`.

```js
console.log( 1 % 2 );
console.log( 1 % 3 );
```

Comment: another `else/default` condition would be more understandable.

Comment: @AZ_ Right. Updated the answer.

Comment: thats much easier to understand now. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your code the console is out of if-else condition, means that it is printing i from condition and out of condition, Your for-loop start from 1, when i=1, condition skipped and console executed and print i which is equal to one
I think that's why
And 
I % 3 == 0 means I % 3 == false
because

```
var i = 2;
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
    console.log(0)
}
if (i % 2 == false)
{
    console.log(0)
}
```

all the answer is 0

Comment: I think what you've said is probably correct, but it's almost incomprehensible due to the complete lack of punctuation, sentences or formatting. Please try and write clearly, and then people can understand you. If you edit this answer to be clear, it will be likely to get upvotes instead of downvotes.